Hypothetical electrical failure in Aérospatiale SA 315B Lama in flight
What would happen to the functioning of the turboshaft engine of the Lama, if you have an electrical failure in flight?
A failure equivalent to turning the battery and generator off.

As stated "the functioning of the turboshaft engine"

Nothing will happen to the engine. You will probably lose engine indications and the ability to restart, but the engine will keep running.
